# Starling AS3 mobile app check if user session is still valid every x seconds

Tags: actionscript-3

I am building a mobile app that requires a login. I am storing a PHP session on the server and the session ID in the app. During app operations (get profile information, get notifications etc) I pass the session ID back to the server to ensure the operation that is requested has a valid session. This works great however I was wondering what the best method would be to intermittently check if the user has a valid session. The reason being that if the same user logs into the app from another device I would like to log them out on the previous device.

I am using a network change event to listen for changes in the network connectivity which works great.

Is there a built in feature to ping a server every x seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally no. You should manually check if your session is "valid". You can start timer in your API class.
Perhaps you have singleton class ServerAPI which has methods to communicate with your server, add timer to its constructor:

```
package {
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class ServerAPI extends EventDispatcher
{
    final var sessionTimeout:int = 20 * 60 * 1000;
    final var sessionTimer:Timer;
    public function ServerAPI () 
    {
        sessionTimer = new Timer(sessionTimeout)
        sessionTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onSessionCheck)
        sessionTimer.start()
    }

    private function onSessionCheck(e:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        //executes every 20 minutes
        //checks session with URL request
    }

    public function anotherMethod(callback:Function, parameter1:int, parameter2:String){
         //do whatever 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was going to be the way if no built in function.